# Detect "public status" of a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking at the Facebook [app endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app) and it looks like you can get a lot of data about an app there. However I noticed it was not possible to detect whether the app had been made public or not.

I have an app access token (id and secret), is there a way this can be checked for without manually logging into the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the app ID in an API call.

http://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID

If public, HTTP 200 and response shown

If not public, HTTP 400 with

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

This above concept just plays on errors in the API. This isn't the defined way to determine public status. Just an educated guess. For the above no access token is used. Thus the call isn't scoped by application. Using a user access token will defeat the purpose here unless it's a token that is not connected in anyway to the app.

A similar concept is possible in FQL

`SELECT app_id,namespace FROM application WHERE app_id=APP_ID`

where an empty response defines an application you cannot see.

---

Of course I could have just stated and started with the obvious, **there is no such method in the API** and leave it at that which is the answer to this question, but I'm showing how one would arrive close to guessing it with these concepts of which is what you wanted

- public status that
- can be checked for without manually logging into the app

Comment: This doesn't tell you if the app is in development mode, it tells you that you can't see the app, which could be for many other reasons in addition to the app being in development mode

Comment: Nice idea! It's not 100% correct, as it depends on the access token you use. If you use a USER access token for a user who is not an admin/tester/developer/insights user of the app, and the app is not public. The error above will be shown. However if you use an APP access token, the error will never show.

Comment: @Igy It's not really a concrete idea but based on the gist of it; being able to check if one can see an app or not; it seems to do a good enough job. That's not to say there are exceptions out there that disprove it. I can match similar in FQL with an APP Token of an unrelated app `SELECT app_id,namespace FROM application WHERE app_id=APP_ID` where an empty response defines an application you cannot see. I'm sure there are other ways to prove this by playing with bugs in the API but yes there is no defined way to prove it, this is just playing with bugs and errors to come to an educated guess

Comment: @phwd even simpler to use no access token, agreed.

Comment: The idea of using 'no' access token only applies to API version 1.0, which will be removed at the and of April 2015, unless you need this only very temporarily you should consider other options